# MongoDB group by column

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do something similar to

```
select column, count(*) 
  from table
 group by column
```

in MongoDB.

I tried

```
db.table.group( {
    key: 'column',
    initial: {sum:0},
    reduce: function(doc, prev) { prev.sum += 1; } }
})
```

I wanted to use something like $sum, but it was not working.

For

```
db.table.group( {
    key: 'column'
} )
```

I'm getting

```
uncaught exception: group command failed: { "errmsg" : "$reduce has to be set", "ok" : 0 }
```

my mongoDB version is 2.0.8 (so I cannot use aggregation framework).

According to result I'm not getting the result for grouped column values, but result for

```
select count(*) from table
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: (data added)

```
> db.table.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50e180ce9449299428db83e8"), "column" : "a", "cnt" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50e180d09449299428db83e9"), "column" : "b", "cnt" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50e180d19449299428db83ea"), "column" : "c", "cnt" : 3 }
> db.table.group( { key: 'column', initial: { sum: 0}, reduce: function(doc, prev) { prev.sum += 1; } } )
[ { "sum" : 3 } ]
```

Maybe I'm using it in wrong way, but I expect

```
[ { "a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1 } ]
```

Comment: check out the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/commands/#group it is `$reduce` not `reduce`, that's literally what that error means.

Comment: MongoDB accepts `reduce` instead of `$reduce`, and I'm getting same wrong result when I'm using `$reduce` :-(

Comment: Be aware that `group` does not work when sharding is enabled. In that case, you may be forced to use aggregation framework or map-reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` should be an object, not just a field name and you have an extra trailing `}` on the `reduce` line.

Try this instead:

```js
db.table.group({
    key: {column: 1},
    initial: {sum:0},
    reduce: function(doc, prev) { prev.sum += 1; }
})
```

Comment: @Betlista I updated the answer to address a problem with the `key` as well.